# How to save a xml file on Java server Application?

Tags: web-services, rest

I 'm developing a rest web service with jersey, in pojo class, I want to save a xml file, and later get the path to this file ?

Answer (score 0):

Due I was using google app engine, and I deployed my app on GAE platform, google doesn't allow th permission to save files on theirs servers, the only solution I find is to use google datastore with Objectify API to save my objects.